# How do I read an R RDS model object into Python to make predictions?

Tags: python, r, serialization

I've read plenty of posts explaining how to read an R RDS object into Python using the rpy2 package. However, I can't seem to find any example on how to read in an R RDS model object in Python and use it to make predictions. I have created a Random Forest model in R and would like to use it within Python to make predictions. Don't ask why, it's a long story, but I've been asked to get this done so I have to. Any help/tips or direction to resources is greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Hi, I know there is a package named ``pyreadr`` to read R files such as ``.RDS`` and ``RData`` in Python. I guess you could give it a try. I'm not sure if ``rpy2`` can read those R RDS models directly.

Comment: This is probably doomed. If you want to use the stored model object for predictions, you'll need the R implementation of random forests. I suspect it would be quite a bit of work to re-implement the prediction from the saved object in Python.